# pendrive bootable from .img file

Tags: linux, terminal, bootable

I have downloaded android-x86-1.6-r2_usb.img and want to create my pendrive as bootable in linux environment can anyone please suggest me steps in command line.

Answer (score 2):

1. Plug the USB drive in one of computer's USB ports.
2. Identify USB disk's device name by typing:
   ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/*usb*
3. Write the USB disk (must be root) by typing:
   dd if=/path/to/file/downloaded of=/dev/sdb

WARNINGS:

- Make sure you replace “sdb” in the example above with the appropriate drive.
- dd will erase all data of the device selected!

  From the example image above, sdb is the USB disk, located under /dev/sdb

  1. Unmount the device (must be root) by typing: umount /dev/sdb